# Question about XmlElement.InnerText and whitespace

Tags: .net, xml

I have an XML element that looks something like this:

```
<content locale="en"> </content>
```

The text between the bracketed stuff consists of a single space character. When I load the XML into an XmlDocument look at the XmlElement object for the above element, I expect:

```
contentElement.InnerText.Length == 1; // InnerText should be a single space character
```

but instead what I get is

```
contentElement.InnerText.Length == 0;
```

Assuming this is not a bug in Microsoft's DOM implementation, is this a feature of the XML/DOM specification I'm not aware of? If so, do I have any options but to add escaped whitespace characters when the XML is written out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have whitespace preserved inside of your XML file after being parsed please consider using `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` section to let parser know that it should take this  character data literally...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about .net in particular, but the xml specifications are unclear about "whitespace nodes" (text nodes with nothing but whitespace. So implementations differ. Most libraries do have a method to start/stop (the opposite of the default) processing whitespace nodes.

The reason whitespace nodes do not have clearly defined behaviour is that you'll inadvertently have a lot of them when using a clean format:

```
<outerTag>
  <innerTag />
</outerTag>
```

That actually has two whitespace nodes!